# Polynomial irreducibility

Tags: contest-math, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_p$ be $p$ positive integers. Let $d=\gcd(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_p)$. Show that the polynomial $$\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^px^{n_i}\right)-p}{x^d-1}$$is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

I'm not sure how to approach this question. Since $p$ is a prime then the question is begging me to use Eisenstein's Criterion but I can't figure out how to apply it. Should there be a clever substitution? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but you can split up the fraction into the sum of the $p$ fractions $(x^{n_i}-1)/(x^d-1)$.

Comment: @B.Goddard I tried that. I didn't get anywhere =(

Comment: And then you can make that a geometric sum.

Comment: I believe the right tool here are Newton's polygons, which can be consider a generalization of Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Can you elaborate?

Comment: @XTL I have started to write up something, but I have no time now, perhaps later.